# last backup - how many backup files and where they are?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, dmv, msdb

I am restoring a database, this database is very big and it has 6 backup files (meaning the backup is split into 6 smaller files)
I can see an indication of that using the [restore labelonly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-labelonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

> MediaFamilyId uniqueidentifier    Unique identification number for the
> media family.

> MediaSequenceNumber   int Sequence number of this media in the media family.

here are the restore commands:

```
   restore filelistonly 
     FROM DISK = '\\MY_BACKUP_SERVER\SQLBackups\MY_SERVER\MY_DATABASE\FULL\MY_SERVER_MY_DATABASE_FULL_20231215_180002_6.bak'

 restore labelonly
  FROM DISK = '\\MY_BACKUP_SERVER\SQLBackups\MY_SERVER\MY_DATABASE\FULL\MY_SERVER_MY_DATABASE_FULL_20231215_180002_6.bak'

restore headeronly
   FROM DISK = '\\MY_BACKUP_SERVER\SQLBackups\MY_SERVER\MY_DATABASE\FULL\MY_SERVER_MY_DATABASE_FULL_20231215_180002_6.bak'
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

My question is, how can I find (in this case 6) files inside msdb?

Basically a query to get these 6 - the last full backup - restore these (6) files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to Find the Backup Files and then Restore the Database.

Find Backup Files

```
    SELECT 
    bs.database_name,
    bmf.physical_device_name,
    bs.backup_start_date,
    bs.backup_finish_date,
    bs.media_set_id
    FROM 
    msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf
    INNER JOIN 
    msdb.dbo.backupset bs ON bmf.media_set_id = bs.media_set_id
    WHERE 
    bs.database_name = 'radhe' -- targeting the "radhe" database
    AND bs.type = 'D' -- 'D' for full database backup
    ORDER BY 
    bs.backup_start_date DESC
```

Restore the database

```
    RESTORE DATABASE [radhe]
    FROM  
    DISK = N'\\Path\To\Backup_Part1.bak',
    DISK = N'\\Path\To\Backup_Part2.bak',
    DISK = N'\\Path\To\Backup_Part3.bak',
    DISK = N'\\Path\To\Backup_Part4.bak',
    DISK = N'\\Path\To\Backup_Part5.bak',
    DISK = N'\\Path\To\Backup_Part6.bak'
    WITH NORECOVERY; 
    -- Use NORECOVERY if you have differential 
    -- or log backups to apply after this.
```

NOTE: Replace \Path\To\Backup_PartX.bak with the actual file paths for each part of your backup set.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I put together the query that would give me the 6 backup files
for the latest full backup:

```
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
    SET NOCOUNT ON
     SELECT 
        
        bs.database_name,
        bmf.physical_device_name,
        bs.backup_start_date,
        bs.backup_finish_date,
        bs.media_set_id

         FROM msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf
   INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bs 
           ON bmf.media_set_id = bs.media_set_id
        WHERE 
        1=1
        and bs.media_set_id in 
        ( 
                                    SELECT top 1
                                    bs.media_set_id
                                    FROM 
                                    msdb.dbo.backupset bs 
                                    WHERE 
                                    bs.database_name = 'radhe' -- targeting the "radhe" database
                                     
                                    AND bs.type = 'D' -- 'D' for full database backup
                                    ORDER BY 
                                    bs.backup_start_date DESC
        )
```

this is the result set:

[image]